# Issue with Nohup dying after a few days- running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, nohup

I'm running a python script in the background on my virtual machine. The script with nohup works fine for a couple days but the background process seems to die after a few more.

Could Compute Engine interfere with this? I'm not sure why the process would die without me ending it. Is there a way to figure out exactly why nohup stopped?

Comment: did you resolve this?